# Como faço para pegar um registro salvo no banco Cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2

Boa noite, como faço para pegar um campo específico na minha tabela. Queria pegar esse campo e receber em uma variável e mostrar na view. Obrigado!!

Comment: Explica um pouco melhor, como é a tabela, qual campo quer pegar, como é o seu model, seu controller e sua view. Use o link de [edit] da pergunta para acrescentar essas informações.

Comment: tabela sales com o campo valor, quero pegar ele e colocar em uma variável chamada $total e enviar para a view

Comment: SalesController, Sale, gerei tudo belo bake

Answer (score 3):

A view é relativa ao mesmo model da tabela ou diferente? Se for o mesmo:

```
 $total = $sales['Sale']['valor'];
```

Se for diferente, no controller da sua view, fica:

```
 public function view(){
         $this->loadModel('Sale');
            $sales = $this->Sale->find('list', array('fields' => array('Sale.valor')));
            $this->set('valor', $valor);
```

Então na view.ctp:

```
 $total = $valor['Sale']['valor'];
```